# Почему при подключении функции не видны переменные?

Tags: javascript, функции, переменные

```
function my_function() {
    var num_num = 1;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    my_function();
    alert(num_num);
});
```

В логе пишет `Uncaught ReferenceError: num_num is not defined`. Как можно передать в `ready(function ()` переменную `num_num` ?

Comment: А почему, например, не возвращать `num_num` как результат выполнения функции? Обошлось бы без глобальных переменных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var num_num = 0; 
function my_function() {
     num_num = 1;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    my_function();
    alert(num_num);
});
```

Хотя вариант который предлагает  Regent более правильный:

```
function my_function() {
    var num_num = 1;
    return num_num;
}
$(document).ready(function () {

    alert(my_function());
});
```

Comment: Спасибо !!!!!!!

Comment: Я пытался сделать так. В функции: `var right = -Math.floor((window_width - text_page_1_width) * (23 / 30)); return right;`. В главной функции: `var new_right = right;
            alert(new_right);`. Что тут не так?

Comment: Ну может я не знаю как правильно вызывать переменную? Просто через alert (так как у вас) всё работает. А получить переменую что-то не получается никак

Comment: var new_right = my_function();

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Объявите переменную снаружи функции, а не внутри.